# DrawerLayout Causing Slow Selector

Tags: android

I started implementing DrawerLayout in my application and I noticed that the selector for my button responds very slowly.  When I change DrawerLayout to LinearLayout, the lag disappears. I'm not sure if this is caused by extra touch processing occurring in the DrawerLayout that causes this lag or something else.  Is there anything I can do to reduce this lag?

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent">

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/my_button"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         android:background="@drawable/button_background"
         android:text="" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="#000080"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="#0000ff"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DrawerLayout doesn't override shouldDelayChildPressedState() like LinearLayout does so it creates a delay.  Had to create a layout class like this:

```
public class MyDrawerLayout extends DrawerLayout {

    public MyDrawerLayout (Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MyDrawerLayout (Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public MyDrawerLayout (Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldDelayChildPressedState() {
        // prevents touch delay
        return false;
    }
}
```

The only side effect I notice is the swipe gesture will select the view before bringing the drawer out.